CSST pipe fpr propane
I live in NH. I had my 100 gal propane tank, which used to sit right next to my house, moved about 25 feet away from the house. I ran 3 inch PVC pipe from the previous outside house connection to the where the tank was moved. I ran 1 and 1/2 inch liquid tight conduit in the PVC pipe and installed 1/2 inch yellow CSST in the liquid tight conduit. My propane company came up with all kinds of reasons why this would not work from saying CSST pipe cannot be used underground to saying it could not be used in liquid tight conduit to saying CSST is not allowed in NH. They wanted to dig everything up and start over using poly pipe. I told them to come up with an alternative without removing the PVC and liquid tight conduit and they left.
So my question is are they FOS and just trying to get $$ out of me to redo the job or are any of their reasons legit? I've had problems with this company before giving me false and misleading information. Any info would be appreciated.

Follow the codes in your area for gas pipes. Errors can have very obvious consequences...

I’m voting to close this question because there are codes covering outside gas pipe specifications unique to each area.
